# iOS app looking for component like Facebook options

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm looking for a component like the facebook status's options view. Example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ8RA.jpg

I mean a view who comes from bottom of app and that you can slide to close, pretty common on iOS app but it looks like there is no native component to do that and I can't find anything on Google or here..

Does anyone have a solution to do that ? Thanks

Comment: My demo https://github.com/PrashantKT/BottomCardView

Comment: those are custom component. even you can create your custom component subclassing UIView. add gesture and animation to present.

Comment: For that there no any native component available. You must have to create your custom design : UIView or UIVIewController with native controls.

Comment: If I add controls/gesture to my custom uiview, will the view follow the swipe gesture ? (to close the uiview in a clean and smooth way)